# python int object not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got the following code:

```
import random
random.seed(57)
c = {}
for key in l:
```

this is using two numbers from the value of dictionary -l- as a range for the random no

```
pos = random in range(l[1[0]], l[1[1]]) 
    c["l[0]"] = pos
return c
```

When I run the doctest in CMD it tells me that the int object is not subscribtable
I'm running the following doctest:

```
>>> ranPos({'Dennis': [90.0, 0.0]})
{'Dennis': 90.0}`
```

Comment: This isn't anything approaching valid code.

Comment: What are `1[0]` and `1[1]` supposed to mean? I think those are supposed to be `l[0]` and `l[1]`, respectively.

Comment: Value in dictionary and then the second value in that tuple
The dictionary is formatted
{key, (tuple, tuple)}

Comment: I think what you are probably meaning by `l[1[0]]` is `l[1][0]`.  Other than that, I have no idea what the code is doing.

Comment: Sorry, new to python
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's count the errors.

`1[0]` means 'take the first index of 1'. Obviously, 1 is an int, and doesn't have indexes. You presumably mean `l[1][0]`, ie 'take the first index of the second index of `l`'.

Next, `random in range()` makes no sense. That is doing a test to see if the object referred to by the name `random` is in the range that you specify. Well, since `random` is a module, it will probably not be in a range of ints. Did you perhaps means `random.randrange(...)`?

Thirdly, you have somehow switched to a string when indexing `c`. That means that all your results will be stored at the same index in c, ie that referred to by that string. Perhaps you meant `c[str(l[0])]`?

Comment: You've helped a lot.
Sorry, I'm new to python and prone to mistakes
Many thanks